# Scanner(System.in).nextLine() blocking my game

Tags: java, parsing

I'm currently making a simple 2D RPG game in Java.

I got the render & tick methods done, the game is working fine.

Now I want to implement a console where the user can type some commands and interact with the map.

The problem is when I start the game, it is just freezing. The freeze is caused by Scanner(System.in).nextLine(). Here's my parser class :

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Parser 
{
private CommandWords aValidCommands;  
private Scanner      aReader;  


public Parser() 
{
    this.aValidCommands = new CommandWords();
    this.aReader        = new Scanner( System.in );
} // Parser()


public Command getCommand() 
{
    String vInputLine;   
    String vWord1 = null;
    String vWord2 = null;

    System.out.print( "> " ); 



    vInputLine = this.aReader.nextLine();  


    Scanner vTokenizer = new Scanner( vInputLine );
    if ( vTokenizer.hasNext() ) {
        vWord1 = vTokenizer.next();      
        if ( vTokenizer.hasNext() ) {
            vWord2 = vTokenizer.next();  

        } 
    } 

    if ( this.aValidCommands.isCommand( vWord1 ) ) {

        return new Command( vWord1, vWord2 );
    }
    else {
        return new Command( null, null ); 
    }
} // getCommand()
} // Parser
```

and my tick function (which is called 60 times/sec)

```
Parser aParser = new Parser();
Command command = aParser.getCommand();
```

The game just freezes when it reaches the line "vInputLine = this.aReader.nextLine(); ". I have no idea why.

Also the parser class is working fine, I already made a console-based RPG using this class. I just don't know why it freezes when I try to implement it in my 2D game.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's supposed to block. Until you enter something on the console. What did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: You should use threads..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner.nextLine()` is a blocking call. This means it will make the current thread wait until it returns a value. If you want to receive input through your scanner, aswell as possibly do other things at the same time, youll need another thread.

```
class Test {

     private static Scanner scanner;
     private static Thread inputThread = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
             scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

             while(true) {
                  //scanner.nextLine();
             }
         }
     }; 

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          inputThread.start();

          //handle everything else on main thread
     }
}
```

Because your scanner is receiving input on one thread, and possibly handling thr input on the other, you should start thinking of ways of passing values from thread-0 (the new thread) to the main thread (which calls the main method).

There are many ways of doing this, the most basic probably being adding input data to a list right when it comes in, then retreive it from the list on your other thread. But keep in mind, when using multiple threads, you need to worrry about memory inconsistancy. If both objects are trying to access the same object (in this case, the list containing the data), things might not calculate as expected. This is where synchronization come in: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: I understand that I have to use threads, but when I mean freeze, I don't mean a simple pause which is understandable, I really mean freeze. I can't even enter anything in the console.

Comment: @user3601853 So when your program gets to that line, it won't allow you to type in the console? Or when you enter something, nothing happens?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to type anything. There's just the welcome message i've put in the console, then nothing. Can't type anything, can't move on the game. The game just freezes when the code gets to that line.

Comment: @user3601853 You're sure the application didn't terminate, right? If the application doesnt terminate, are you currently using multiple threads? Without the rest of your code, its hard to see what the problem is. It could be that, at the time the user should input something into the console, the lock for the console or in-stream is occupied. From what you've shown and asked us, your issue is that readLine is a blocking call. Be more specific

Answer (score 0):

It happens so because it actually does not finishes the line.

For example:

Code:

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        
  int a, b;        
  String name;
        
  System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
        
  a = scan.nextInt();
  b = scan.nextInt();        
        
  System.out.println("Sum of " +a+ " and " +b+ " is " +(a+b));
  System.out.println("Please enter your name");        
  name = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println(""+name);
```

Output :

```
Enter two numbers
1
2
Sum of 1 and 2 is 3
Please enter your name -> And it freezes here.
```

It happens as nextLine is still in waiting as this code `(System.out.println(""+name);)` just prints and does not finishes the line.